# Deploy seperate repo to Heroku subdomain

Tags: heroku, deployment, subdomain

I have 2 domains setup for my Heroku app.

1. **wwww.bar.com**
2. **foo.bar.com**

I want to be able to deploy my Github repo's to seperately to each domain.

1. Repo 1 deploy to **wwww.bar.com**
2. Repo 2 deploys to **foo.bar.com**

I added my subdomain using:

```
heroku domains:add foo.bar.com -a bar
```

Currently in my Heroku, there only seems to be one Repo that I can deploy from, and this doesn't seem to be a simple configuration. Has anyone any experience with this that could offer some advice.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two repositories and two domains, these should be two separate applications on Heroku.

Comment: Even if it's just a subdomain?

Comment: @danjones_mcr you can easily have multiple domains on one app, them being subdomains or not. But for each app there can be only one repository